# Spring Security with filters permitAll not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've got this security config:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(
                    new JwtLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(
                    new JwtAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

The two filters are doing authentication work: loginFilter checks credentials in the post body and then add cookie to the response. The authenticationFilter checks the auth cookie.

However, permitAll does not let the root route and "/register" route pass (aka. still going through the authenticationFilter, which I thought permitAll would let these routes pass the filters)

What's wrong?

Comment: I know I can use webSecurity.ignoring to work around this, but why above code won't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[permitAll()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#permitAll--) does not ignore filters. It simply grants access regardless of whether or not an [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) is present in a request's security context after all filters have been processed.

You should check your filters and any [AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) implementations that they use to to ensure that they are not breaking the execution flow of Spring Security by throwing unchecked/uncaught exceptions or expressly sending a response on a failed authentication.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the links are broken. Could you please help me?