# Spring's basic security overwriting app's configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot 2 app with Spring security, as follow:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [(SecurityAutoConfiguration::class)])
class UntappdCqrsApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<UntappdCqrsApplication>(*args)
}
```

and the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class TokenConfiguration(
        val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

        http.apply(JwtTokenConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

There are two endpoints: `POST users/signup` and `GET users/test`.
According to my configuration, /signup should not require authentication and /test should, but both endpoints are accessible without any authentication.

If I add `@EnableWebSecurity` in my `TokenConfiguration` class, Spring now generates a default password and both endpoints are now protected.

I think I'm missing something here, but I have no idea what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the source or imports for your JwtTokenProvider or JwtTokenConfigurer classes, but it seems likely that your JwtTokenProvider is throwing an unchecked exception or even directly sending a response on authentication failure. This will prevent permitAll() from ever being triggered.

See my response to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086769/873590