# Why antMatchers not working and trying to authenticate Login route?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am having trouble making authentication API in spring security.

I have the setup for the JWT login and register routes with Spring Security OncePerRequestFilter.
For some reason, When I try to login myself in, it also tries to run `doFilter` method.
Meaning, even though the user is trying to login with `username and password`, my api looks for `jwt Bearer token`.

I have my `SecurityConfig.java` as follows but the antMatchers do not work for `login` path as I thought.

Can someone help me please?

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api-docs", "/swagger").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v0/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(this.jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(this.bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(this.appUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v0/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) throws Exception {
        AuthResponse response = this.authService.login(request);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
// ..... the rest
```

When I access `/api-docs", "/swagger"`, the API does not try to authenticate.
But the API does for `/api/v0/auth/login`, because I can see the log I added in doFilter in the log after sending request to `/api/v0/auth/login`

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        String userName = null;
        log.info("@@ doFilterInternal: {}", authorization);
        
        // jwt and authentication stuff

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

// what I see in the log for login request
// 2023-01-22 09:49:06.716  INFO 15780 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.h.s.config.security.filter.JwtFilter   : @@ doFilterInternal: null
```

Since I added a login endpoint in antMatchers, it should not log this and skip the authentication I believe.
Can someone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: any reason to why you are not using the built in JWT authentication filter that exists in spring security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post, with a HttpSecurity config for permitAll you are not bypassing filters -> [Spring Security with filters permitAll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068433/spring-security-with-filters-permitall-not-working).  If you do not want to have your filter be called, you can move that url exclude config to WebSecurity set up as below

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/api/v0/auth/login");
}
```

or you can add url exclude to OncePerRequestFilter as below -

```
private final RequestMatcher uriMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v0/auth/login", HttpMethod.GET.name());

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return uriMatcher.matches(request);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much !!! It worked. I just wonder why I was able to access "/api-docs", "/swagger" endpoints without the two solutions you gave me whereas "/api/v0/auth/login" does not.