# Spring Boot Filter called in anonymous request

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

Lil problem with Spring Security: I have two 'main-endpoints' in my app. `/authenticated/**` & `/anonymous/**`. The name of each endpoint is pretty much what I also want Spring Boot to do.

`SecurityConfig`:

```java
@Bean
open fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {

    httpSecurity
        .csrf { }
        .httpBasic { it.disable() }
        .formLogin { it.disable() }
        .authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.requestMatchers(*AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        .addFilterAfter(JWTAuthenticationFilter(), AuthorizationFilter::class.java)

    return httpSecurity.build()
}
```

In previous projects I just used to create a second `AUTH_WHITELIST`, which would then be checked in the `shouldNotFilter` method of - in this case - `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.

I figured that there has to be some other way to achieve the same result of 'anonymous' requests *not* being filtered, but as of now, I haven't found a way to do so.

My current understanding of the filter chain isn't all too great, even though I've read some docs and read through countless posts on this website. 
-> Tried with various orders (resp. placements) of my custom filter in the filter chain in the hope of somehow setting it back far enough, for `.authorizeHttpRequests` to do its job, before being called.

Cheers

Comment: I've finally found this answer and this is good enough for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086769/14442758. Won't close tho, as there still might be another answer somewhere.